# Lee-Ready tick test using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to build Lee-Ready tick test for estimating trade direction from tick data using Excel. I have a dataset containing the trade prices in descending order, and I am trying to build a VBA code that is able to loop over all the 4m+ cells in as efficient manner as possible.

The rule for estimating trade direciton goes as follows:

```
If Pt>Pt-1, then d=1
If Pt<Pt-1, then d=-1
If Pt=Pt-1, then d is the last value taken by d.
```

So to give a concrete example, I would like to transform this:

```
P1;P2;P3;P4
1.01;2.02;3.03;4.04
1.00;2.03;3.03;4.02
1.01;2.02;3.01;4.04
1.00;2.03;3.00;4.04
```

into this

```
d1;d2;d3;d4
1;-1;1;1
-1;1;1;-1
1;-1;1;0
0;0;0;0
```

Comment: You will get more & better answers when you show what you have already tried.

Comment: How does the last row of zeros mesh with your rules? The rules seem to imply that d is always either +1 or -1.

Comment: The trade direction will not be estimated for the first trade of the day, i.e. it could as well be N/A, simply implying that it can't be stated based on the rules.

Comment: So going down the rows is going back in time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly straightforward nested loops suffice:

```
Function LeeReady(Prices As Variant) As Variant
    'Given a range or 1-based, 2-dimensional variant array
    'Returns an array of same size
    'consisiting of an array of the same size
    'of trade directions computed according to
    'Lee-Ready rule

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim m As Long, n As Long
    Dim priceData As Variant, directions As Variant
    Dim current As Variant, previous As Variant

    If TypeName(Prices) = "Range" Then
        priceData = Prices.Value
    Else
        priceData = Prices
    End If

    m = UBound(priceData, 1)
    n = UBound(priceData, 2)
    ReDim directions(1 To m, 1 To n) As Long 'implicitly fills in bottom row with 0s

    For i = m - 1 To 1 Step -1
        For j = 1 To n
            current = priceData(i, j)
            previous = priceData(i + 1, j)
            If current > previous Then
                directions(i, j) = 1
            ElseIf current < previous And previous > 0 Then
                directions(i, j) = -1
            Else
                directions(i, j) = directions(i + 1, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    LeeReady = directions

End Function
```

This can be called from a sub or used directly on the worksheet:

[image]

Here I just highlighted a block of cells of the correct size to hold the output and then used the formula `=LeeReady(A2:D5)` (pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to accept it as an array formula).

On Edit: I modified the code slightly (by adding the clause `And previous > 0` to the `If` statement in the main loop) so that it can now handle ranges in which come of the columns have more rows than other columns. The code assumes that price data is always > 0 and fills in the return array with 0s as place holders in the columns that end earlier than other columns:

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir! How should I go about editting this code if the columns are not of equal length?

Comment: The easy fix would be to just call it on each column separately.

Comment: @Ana I tweaked it a bit so as to handle the case of columns of unequal length.